# Let $Y = \lim_{t \to \infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{ X \le t\}}$. Is $Y =\mathbf{1}_{\{ X < +\infty\}}$ or $Y = \mathbf{1}_{\{ X \le +\infty\}}$

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable that values in $\mathbb R\cup \{\pm\infty\}$. Consider the limit $$Y = \lim_{t \to \infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{ X \le t\}}$$

I'm not sure if $Y =\mathbf{1}_{\{ X < +\infty\}}$ or $Y = \mathbf{1}_{\{ X \le +\infty\}}$.

Could you please elaborate on which one is correct? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, in the final expression you are looking for, there should not be any limit in $t$ of a quantity that does not depend on $t$. Take $\omega\in\Omega$. If $X(\omega)<+\infty$, then $\mathbf{1}_{X\leqslant t}(\omega)=1$ when $t\geqslant X(\omega)$ hence $Y(\omega)=1$. If $X(\omega)=+\infty$, then for all $t\in\mathbb R$, $\mathbf{1}_{X\leqslant t}(\omega)= 0$ hence $Y(\omega)=0$. Conclusion: $Y(\omega)=\mathbf{1}_{X<+\infty}$.

Comment: Thank you for your very clear explanation :))

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{t \to \infty} 1_{X\leq t} =1_{X<\infty}$. Note that for any real number $t$ $X\leq t$ implies $X <\infty$ .